# Why GCC can compile std::exception("some error msg") without error?

Tags: c++

I found the following code that is throwing an exception with a message for the parameter, but GCC can successfully compile it without any error.

When I use clang to compile, the result is failure. I want to debug the GCC compile process to find the difference with the GCC option `-Q`, but it seems not to work. I hope someone can give me some advice, or tell me why GCC can compile it successfully.

```
T* lpItem = new T;
if (NULL == lpItem)
{
    throw std::exception("New CachePool Item Fail");
}
```

Comment: Look at the sourcecode for the `std::exception` class.

Comment: There is a chance that GCC is discarding that code, since `new` must always return a valid pointer.  Alternatively, there may be a non-standard extension permitting that constructor.  If you want to throw a `std::exception` with a message, use [std::runtime_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error).

Comment: @paddy Even if it can prove that it's never called, is has to be valid C++ (ignoring special cases like `constexpr if` for a moment)

Comment: While `std::exception("New CachePool Item Fail")` is *likely* to be non-compliant, nothing can be definitely said about a program fragnent. This is why [mcve] is important. Please make sure you include your compilation command and any error messages you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is taking advantage of [`[member.functions]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions) to add something like

```
std::exception::exception(const char *);
```

Clang is not

> For a non-virtual member function described in the C++ standard library, an implementation may declare a different set of member function signatures, provided that any call to the member function that would select an overload from the set of declarations described in this document behaves as if that overload were selected. [ *Note:* For instance, an implementation may add parameters with default values, or replace a member function with default arguments with two or more member functions with equivalent behavior, or **add additional signatures** for a member function name. — *end note* ]

Emphasis added